# Did Plaid Change Something About It's MFA?

Tags: plaid

I had this little piece of code working perfectly returning account and transactions objects in response to the Plaid MFA questions.  I'm not sure what went wrong as I (had not until it stopped working and I've since tried a few things) did not touch the code (to my recollection) and even checked several previous working versions to be safe.  Anyhow I now get the following list of errors given the scenario:

1) If I try to US Bank MFA, it returns an MFA and after I answer it also returns a account and transactions object.  At the end of that info in my terminal it also returns events.js 85 throw er; // Unhandled error event

2) If I try USAA or Bank of America I get the following error object for my response:

```
{ code: 1203,
  message: 'invalid mfa',
  resolve: 'The MFA response provided was not correct.',
  access_token: 'test_bofa' }
```

It returns the MFA question though and when I answer with 'again', I get:

```
{ type: 'questions',
  mfa: [ { question: 'You say tomato, I say...?' } ],
  access_token: 'test_bofa' }
```

events.js:85 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

```
    plaid.connect({username: req.body.cardName, password: req.body.cardPass, pin: req.body.pin}, req.body.type,
        'test@plaid.com',
        function (error, response, mfa) {
            if (response == undefined) {
                res.send(response);
            } else if (response.hasOwnProperty('accounts')) {
                res.send(response);
            } else if (response.hasOwnProperty("mfa")) {
                res.send(response);//If I remove this response it kicks me out right away. But with it, I receive an undefined MFA response.
                plaid.step(response.access_token, req.body.answer, function (err, response) {
                        if (response == undefined) {
                            res.send(response);
                        } else if (response.hasOwnProperty("resolve")) {
                            res.send(response);
                        } else if (response.hasOwnProperty('accounts')) {
                            res.send(response);
                        } else if (response.hasOwnProperty('mfa')) {
                            res.send(response);
                        }
                    }
                )
            }

             else {
                response = "error";
                response.send("something went wrong with Plaid");
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it kicks you out right away? What is the JSON that you are sending back for that line? Additionally, have you verified that all of those banks allows the Connect product to be used? Not all banks allow all products.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore as I fixed it and this questions was asked almost a month ago. I was using Plaid.Connect though along with MFA. Hopefully I won't have anymore issues.

Comment: If you're willing to share the code that fixed this problem, that'd be great for future SO visitors. Just put it in an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't "fix" it so to speak.  After spending countless hours over a number of weeks pondering away,  I upgraded to the new Plaid library once it was launched.  That is what 'fixed' the problem.  The node documentation for this library is a significant improvement over the previous documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand during testing mfa code should be string or and array(if there are few questions). So if you enter mfa as an int you will get error.

'again' mfa will call one more mfa loop, and 'tomato' will finalize it.